# Fixing Detected resolved migration not applied to database

Tags: database-migration, flyway

I have never worked with Flyway, but all of a sudden I'm managing it. It appears `outOfOrder` is false by default and I am now working with a failed migration that is blocking continuous deployment to our QA environment. I merged V21__alter_sequence.sql after V22__add_column.sql was already merged. Migrations are all run by a Jenkins build process.

My question is, how do I fix this? My guesses are:

1. merge U21__alter_sequence.sql then merge V23__alter_sequence.sql?
2. update flyway.conf, add line `flyway.outOfOrder=true` and maybe some magic happens on the next merge?

(see my ignorance on this topic!) Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I updated the flyway.conf and reran the build and it appears to have ran the migration. Not sure if this is the correct way to handle this or not.

Comment: Yes, that's a valid way of solving the problem. The risk is if V21 has a dependency on a change made by V22 and could then fail to run.